# Tortoise SVN Side Hooks Scripts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks, svn-client

Can someone help me how to capture the log message in Client-side hooks script i.e., for manual-pre-commit hook in Tortoise SVN.

Thanks !

John

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got the Details.

MESSAGEFILE is a parameter it passes the Log message you have entered during executions. In Manual-precommit it was in $2.

So here what i did,

MESSAGEFILE="$2"

Like we pass REPOS=$1, TXN=$2 in SVN pre-commit.

Hope this helps someone who is googling for Tortoise client hooks.

Comment: could you share your script? I'm having trouble setting it up.